# An error occurred: @Output not initialized

Tags: angular, click, angular-event-emitter

I'm working on an angular app for managers to keep track of their teams, and I'm stuck with an @Output error :

```
An error occurred: @Output deleteMeeting not initialized in 'MeetingItemComponent'.
```

I have a Meetings component, generating a list of MeetingItem components. I want to perform actions when the user clicks on different buttons (edit, delete, show details).

Here is my parent Meetings template :

```
<div class="meeting__list" [@newMeeting]="meetings.length">
  <app-meeting-item
    *ngFor="let meeting of meetings"
    [meeting]="meeting"
    (deleteMeeting)="deleteMeeting($event)"
    (openMeetingDialog)="openMeetingDialog($event)"
    (messageClick)="openMessage($event)"
  ></app-meeting-item>
</div>
```

My MeetingItem template (only the part concerned by this post) :

```
<span class="meeting__actions">
    <mat-icon *ngIf="meeting.message" (click)="onMessageClick(meeting)" matTooltip="Read the message"
      matTooltipPosition="above" class="icon--notes">notes</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon (click)="onOpenMeetingDialog(meeting)" matTooltip="Edit this meeting" matTooltipPosition="above" class="icon--edit">edit</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon (click)="onDeleteMeeting(meeting.id)" matTooltip="Delete this meeting" matTooltipPosition="above" class="icon--delete">delete_outline</mat-icon>
  </span>
```

My MeetingItem component :

```
import { Component, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-meeting-item',
  templateUrl: './meeting-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./meeting-item.component.scss']
})
export class MeetingItemComponent {

  @Input() meeting;

  @Output() deleteMeeting = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() openMeetingDialog = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() messageClick = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}

  onDeleteMeeting(meetingId) {
    this.deleteMeeting.emit(meetingId);
  }

  onOpenMeetingDialog(meeting) {
    this.openMeetingDialog.emit(meeting);
  }

  onMessageClick(meeting) {
    this.messageClick.emit(meeting);
  }
}
```

Comment: Provided code looks fine and would be easier to trace the issue if you can provide stackblitz demo.

Answer (score 615, accepted):

To make your code work in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u6nf7y-wephd9), I had to replace

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
```

with

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: A moment of silence for those who are here due to an auto import from VS code that imported `events` instead of `@angular/core`.

Answer (score 49):

Had the same error,

Import was correct like

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

But the variable definition was wrong:

```
@Output() onFormChange: EventEmitter<any>;
```

Should be:

```
@Output() onFormChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

Comment: Yes. The same error occurs when EventEmitter isn't initialised with the component. I tried initialising it within a function (to reduce initial view load), but Angular won't have it.

Comment: For me I had to move the initialisation into the constructor.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem even importing from `@angular/core`.

**The problem**: I was initializing the `EventEmmitter` object in the `ngOnInit` method from my component class.
**Solution**: I moved the initialization to the component's class constructor.

Answer (score 5):

I had also the same error. I found that **Auto Import** extension of VS Code did this. `import * as EventEmitter from 'events';` is imported instead of `import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';`

So make sure if the import is ok or not.

Answer (score 3):

In your component just use core angular module.
Simply put this code at beginning of file.

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: Your answer seems a copy of part of ConnorsFan's answer. I think you should delete it

Answer (score 3):

change the import : `import { EventEmitter } from 'events';`
with : `import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';`

Comment: add some explanation of what was wrong and how your solution works.

Answer (score 2):

For me it works if I change below imports 
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

to

```
import { Component, Output ,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 2):

`@Output() isAbout: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();` This should be the whole syntax to make it work you need the instance of the event emitter

Answer (score 0):

> I also checked the import and it was completely correct

This error happened exactly to me, but it was when I had written the output in this way

```
@Output() onClick: EventEmitter<any>;
```

But I wrote it this way and my error was fixed

```
@Output() onClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

It is also nice to know that the version of my `Angular project was 12` and it worked well and no errors occurred.
Now that I have updated to `version 16`, this problem has occurred
I said it might be effective